# How to import components in cakephp on the fly

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to import the component in a function using following syntax:

`App::import('Component', 'ImageUploader');`

However, it works if I define it in the class eg:

```
class AbcController extends AppController {
public $name = 'Abc';
public $components = array('ImageUploader');`
}
```

How do I import it in a function? I am using CakePhp latest stable version.

Comment: How exactly does it fail to work?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario it gives error of `Non Object`

Comment: Please edit the question and post the *complete* error message. Also, don't forget to say what line of your code it points to.

Comment: And even more important: What cake php version you are using. In 2.x you dont use App::import, you use App::uses()

Answer (score 1):

From the [Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html#loading-components-on-the-fly)

```
$this->ImageUploader = $this->Components->load('ImageUploader');
```

This, of course, is assuming you're using at least v2 and are wanting to load it within a controller function.